# How to go about extracting data from an api website?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have made an app where it opens up an online api(?) database. I used the ListView widget where each entry (name of something) clicks onto a new activity. I would like to know how to go about extracting data from the database and putting it in my app for example; if I were to get reviews about a shampoo showing on the page and also a picture of the shampoo etc.

Sorry if I make no sense.

Comment: There are too many possible solutions for this. You could narrow it down a bit by giving more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
It would have helped if you post some of your code. 
According to what I understood is that you want to download data from server and show it into your list view.

What you can do is you can hit API in Asynctask. Put each item data like text, image URL etc into one bean class (setter getter) and add that bean into your list attached to your adapter.

Then you can call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.
```

Comment: Kind of. I wanted to extract data from the website and show it in a new page that would open up FROM an item in listview.